# How to pivot and get aggregates for two columns in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So I have a table with some raw data that looks like this:

| event_date | country_code | platform | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 | UK | android | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 | UK | android | 4 |
| 2022-10-02 | FR | ios | 5 |
| 2022-11-02 | UK | android | 144 |
| 2022-12-01 | GR | android | 154 |

And I would like to get the aggregates per day and:

- per country (only for `UK`, `FR` and `ES`, but also for `NOT UK`)
- per platform
- as well as the total installs just for the platforms (without the country combinations)

| event_date | count_ios | count_android | count_ios_non_uk | count_ios_uk | count_ios_fr | count_ios_es | count_android_non_uk | count_android_uk | count_android_fr | count_android_ies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2022-10-02 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2022-11-02 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2022-12-01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I've tried with `PIVOT`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 
    event_date,
    platform,
    country_code
  FROM my_table
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(*) AS count
  FOR LOWER(country_code) IN ('uk', 'fr', 'ie')
)
ORDER BY event_date DESC;
```

but this would only give me the combinations for country codes, and also even for that one I am not entirely sure how to go about `non-uk` use-case as well as the counts per platform-only

Comment: `NOT UK` includes other coutries except `UK`, `FR` and `ES` like `GR` ?

Answer (score -1):

Your aggregations have different conditions, therefore you probably will have a hard time getting all the counts you show.

It's not an elegant solution, but should do the trick:

```sql
WITH
  my_table AS (
    SELECT "2022-10-01" event_date, 'UK' country_code, 'android' platform, 1 user_id union all
    SELECT "2022-10-01", 'UK', 'android', 4   user_id union all
    SELECT "2022-10-02", 'FR', 'ios'    , 5   user_id union all
    SELECT "2022-11-02", 'UK', 'android', 144 user_id union all
    SELECT "2022-12-01", 'GR', 'android', 154 user_id
  )

SELECT DISTINCT
  event_date, 
  (select count(*) from my_table t1 where t1.platform = 'ios' and LOWER(t1.country_code) IN ('uk', 'fr', 'es') and t1.event_date = t0.event_date) count_ios,
  (select count(*) from my_table t1 where t1.platform = 'android' and LOWER(t1.country_code) IN ('uk', 'fr', 'es') and t1.event_date = t0.event_date) count_android,
  (select count(*) from my_table t1 where t1.platform = 'ios' and LOWER(t1.country_code) NOT IN ('uk') and t1.event_date = t0.event_date) count_ios_non_uk,
  (select count(*) from my_table t1 where t1.platform = 'ios' and LOWER(t1.country_code) IN ('uk') and t1.event_date = t0.event_date) count_ios_uk,
  (select count(*) from my_table t1 where t1.platform = 'ios' and LOWER(t1.country_code) IN ('fr') and t1.event_date = t0.event_date) count_ios_fr,
  (select count(*) from my_table t1 where t1.platform = 'ios' and LOWER(t1.country_code) IN ('es') and t1.event_date = t0.event_date) count_ios_es,
  (select count(*) from my_table t1 where t1.platform = 'android' and LOWER(t1.country_code) NOT IN ('uk') and t1.event_date = t0.event_date) count_android_non_uk,
  (select count(*) from my_table t1 where t1.platform = 'android' and LOWER(t1.country_code) IN ('uk') and t1.event_date = t0.event_date) count_android_uk,
  (select count(*) from my_table t1 where t1.platform = 'android' and LOWER(t1.country_code) IN ('fr') and t1.event_date = t0.event_date) count_android_fr,
  (select count(*) from my_table t1 where t1.platform = 'android' and LOWER(t1.country_code) IN ('es') and t1.event_date = t0.event_date) count_android_es,
FROM
  my_table t0
```